# How to find the port used for SCP?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, cygwin, scp

I'm trying to copy a file from my local (Windows 10, Cygwin) machine to a remote (Raspberry Pi) machine using `scp`, I get a time out error:

```
$ scp main.bin root@123.12.21.123:
ssh: connect to host 123.12.21.123 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

Using the `-vvv` option:

```
$ scp -vvv main.bin root@123.12.21.123:
Executing: program ssh.exe host 123.12.21.123, user root, command scp -v -t .
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 123.12.21.123 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 123.12.21.123 [123.12.21.123] port 22.
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10060, io:000001F145E05D40
debug1: connect to address 123.12.21.123 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 123.12.21.123 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

Connection with `ssh` has no problem.

Any idea what is wrong?

Is this a problem with the remote's `scp` port? If so, how do I find the remote's port?

---

**UPDATE 1:** Here's the `ssh` session with debug info. As can be seen it successfully logs in to the remote machine. As far as I can decypher this dump, it does use port 22:

```
$ ssh root@123.12.21.123 -vvv
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 123.12.21.123 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 123.12.21.123 [123.12.21.123] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 123.12.21.123:22 as 'root'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 123.12.21.123
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:ZUOyK+Ds1NrCabdxf0RBG0i4YnI/Vpkrxkhp69S7SVi
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 123.12.21.123
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/myusername/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host '123.12.21.123' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:u5AP4/ZjDZxyoh/Q3fyETBC9G+6lrV7+ioiHVUeP8zO
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:u5AP4/ZjDZxyoh/Q3fyETBC9G+6lrV7+ioiHVUeP8zO
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myusername/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
root@123.12.21.123's password:
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to 123.12.21.123 ([123.12.21.123]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug3: This windows OS supports conpty
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug3: Successfully set console output code page from:65001 to 65001
debug3: Successfully set console input code page from:437 to 65001
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Sat Jan 22 03:11:15 2022 from 123.12.21.124
/home/pi$
```

Also, please note that copying files with WinSCP works fine. Here's the `Server/Protocol information` listing:

```
File transfer protocol = SFTP-3
Cryptographic protocol = SSH-2
SSH implementation = OpenSSH_6.7p1 Raspbian-5+deb8u3
Encryption algorithm = AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated)
Compression = No
------------------------------------------------------------
Server host key fingerprints
SHA-256 = ssh-ed25519 255 GnPCPpStHbhz+WmXNXTcuYNrsU/126Oq2iAmbkJ6Ys4=
MD5 = ssh-ed25519 255 5e:98:cf:a3:98:4c:9d:16:16:f2:03:65:d9:d9:53:cd
------------------------------------------------------------
Can change permissions = Yes
Can change owner/group = Yes
Can execute arbitrary command = No
Can create symbolic/hard link = Yes/Yes
Can lookup user groups = No
Can duplicate remote files = No
Can check available space = Yes
Can calculate file checksum = No
Native text (ASCII) mode transfers = No
------------------------------------------------------------
Additional information
The server supports these SFTP extensions:
  posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
  statvfs@openssh.com="2"
  fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
  hardlink@openssh.com="1"
  fsync@openssh.com="1"
------------------------------------------------------------
Total bytes on device = 29.0 GB (31,221,002,240 B)
Free bytes on device = 24.2 GB (26,007,535,616 B)
Total bytes for user = Unknown
Free bytes for user = 23.0 GB (24,712,527,872 B)
Bytes per allocation unit = 4.00 KB (4,096 B)
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_scanner

Comment: So what port have you defined within OpenSSH daemon configuration file.  What port is your SSH configured to run on?

Comment: I’m not saying you’re lying or anything, but please provide the output of `ssh -vvv root@123.12.21.123`. Also keep in mind that obfuscated IP addresses make answering questions a lot harder. You do not need to obfuscate local IP addresses.

Comment: @Ramhound - I did not define anything. I am using an RPi system that was given to me, and whatever default SSH configuration that was installed by Windows/Cygwin. Where do I find this information?

Comment: @DanielB - I am not *lying*, but the IP address is obfuscated. Why does it matter?

Comment: You say that connection with ssh has no problem. So run ssh with the "-v" flag and make a connection, then [edit] your question to include the ssh debug output.

Comment: @yasp - Unless you provide the OpenSSH server configuration we cannot help. We need the configuration from the server NOT the client.  Without this information your question is probably unanswerable.  Please [edit] your question instead of submitting additional commentary

Comment: Have you seen https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_connection_refused  - This implies the issue may be a firewall issue specifically related to your SCP app.

Comment: @DanielB - sorry, missed the replacement from `scp` to `ssh`. Please see update 1 in the question.

Comment: @Kenster - debug output added.

Comment: @Ramhound - Understood, but how do you find this configuration? I think this is the essence of this question.

Comment: @davidgo - Actually, WinSCP has no problem connecting. This is how I actually copy the files.

Comment: The name of the configuration file for the OpenSSH Server is well documented.  The output of -vvv is very weird, it's attempting to read the server configuration file, on Windows, instead of the RPI.

Comment: The SCP does not have it own port. The "SCP" is a "service" that runs under SSH. If SSH works, SCP should too (assuming you run both on the same machine). App-specific firewall rule might be an explanation, as @davidgo already suggested.